# What is the significance of the transpose of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, transpose

What is the physical meaning of the transpose of a matrix? Geometrically, does it show only reflection or does it have other geometrical significance too?

Comment: Do you know what a basis of a vector space is?  A linear transformation between vector spaces?  And what is a linear functional on a vector space?  To each linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$, which can be represented by a matrix $A$ with the standard basis, the transpose $A^T$ represents the "dual transformation" $T^{\ast}: (\mathbb R^m)^{\ast} \rightarrow (\mathbb R^n)^{\ast}$ with respect to the dual basis.

Comment: What do you consider to be the physical meaning of the original, untransposed matrix?